# converte json to list of object if in one data class list of second data class Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json

I have some json where i send two data information and price of nomenclature.

```
{
    "arr": 
[
  {
    NomenclatureInfo: {
      Code: '',
      Description: '',
      Ref_Key: ''
    },
    Price: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },{
    NomenclatureInfo: {
      Code: '',
      Description: '',
      Ref_Key: ''
    },
    Price: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
}
```

on my android client i convert this all of in onRespounse mhetod retrofit. After get information i convert to type of data class **ResponseJsonTemplates**

```
data class ResponseJsonTemplates (
    @SerializedName("arr")
    var nomList:List<ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel>
)
```

how to convert information to this list of **ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel**

```
data class ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel (
    @SerializedName("NomenclatureInfo")
    var dataName:DataNum,
    @SerializedName("Price")
    var dataPrice:List<PriceOfNom>
)
```

how it i want to do and in this code i have a problem below

```
  override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<ResponseJsonTemplates>,
                        response: Response<ResponseJsonTemplates>
                    ) {

                        var returnElement = response.body()?.nomList.toString()
                        Log.d(TAG, "returnElement: $returnElement")

                        var arrayType = object : TypeToken<List<ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel>>() {}.type
                        var tutorials: List<ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel> =
                            gson.fromJson(returnElement, arrayType)
                        Log.d(TAG, "tutorials = $tutorials")
```

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $[0]

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add the problem you're running into. What's the result?

Comment: sorry i add my error, now i take on respounse List<ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel> and this try exeprion 
```List<ResponseNomenclatureWithPriceModel>```

Comment: And what are you seeing in your LogCat? Because it looks like you're trying to parse the output of List.toString() `returnElement` as JSON. I'd expect the LogCat to confirm that.